# How can I publish a PHP web app on IIS en Windows Server 2016?

Tags: php, iis, dns

Recently I've made a php 8.3.0 web app and it's already on IIS in Virtual Windows Server 2019, but it's just usable with localhost. Is there a way to use it with a regular URL?

This is my first question on stackoverflow, sorry if it's not well related

I've been trying to use a DNS, but it doesn't worked

Comment: If you have registered a domain name, log into your domain name registrar's website and set up a DNS record (A record) that points to your server's external IP address. This may take some time to propagate. Additionally, your IIS site binding needs to be configured with the correct hostname

Comment: What errors do you get when you access using domain name? Please provide the detailed error message you get. ​

Comment: @YurongDai, when I try to use it with my domain it only shows that can't reach the page, but DNS and IIS are working

Comment: Can you access the page via IP address? If you ping your domain name (eg: www.domain.com), do you get the correct IP?

Comment: Hi, it's done, the problem was that I forgot enable both ports (80-443), after that, the web site worked fine, thanks for help @YurongDai